# Method or data member Issue with my Excel VBA Code

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

Hello I started to program a macro and have come across an error stating Method or data member not found and its pointing me to the following line in the code:

```
Set wsSheet = wsTPCC.Sheets("TPCC")
```

I am completely clueless as to why this might be happening and would like to have some assistance in figuring this out but also throughout the rest of the programming as this is only the beginning of my code. Here is the whole code just in case.

```
Option Explicit
Sub TrainingHoursMacro()

Dim wbTHMacro As Workbook, wsRegulares As Worksheet, wsRegularesDemitidos As Worksheet, wsTempActivos As Worksheet, wsTempJA As Worksheet, wsTempFit As Worksheet, _
    wsTempDemitidos As Worksheet, wsPS As Worksheet, wsResultados As Worksheet, wsDLList As Worksheet, wsSheet As Worksheet
Dim wbRegularesBruto As Workbook, wsMovimentacao As Worksheet, wsDemitidos As Worksheet
Dim wbTemporariosBruto As Workbook, wsTemporariosAtivos As Worksheet, wsJAAtivos As Worksheet, wsAprendizesFit As Worksheet
Dim wbPresenceSystem As Workbook, wsTPCC As Worksheet

Set wbTHMacro = Workbooks("Training Hours Macro.xlsm")
Set wsRegulares = wbTHMacro.Sheets("Regulares")
wsRegulares.Cells.ClearContents

Set wbRegularesBruto = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="H:\BX-HR\BX-INDUSTRIAL RELATIONS\HR REPRESENTATIVES\PRIVATE\HRSSC\Brazil\Training Hours Macro\Regulares Bruto.xls")
If Not wbRegularesBruto Is Nothing Then

    Set wsSheet = wbRegularesBruto.Sheets("Movimentacao")
    wsSheet.Cells.Copy wsRegulares.Range("A1")
    Set wsSheet = wbRegularesBruto.Sheets("Demitidos")
    Set wsRegularesDemitidos = wbTHMacro.Sheets("Regulares Demitidos")
    wsSheet.Cells.Copy wsRegularesDemitidos.Range("A1")
    wbRegularesBruto.Close False
Else
    Exit Sub
End If

Set wbTemporariosBruto = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="H:\BX-HR\BX-INDUSTRIAL RELATIONS\HR REPRESENTATIVES\PRIVATE\HRSSC\Brazil\Training Hours Macro\Temporarios Bruto.xlsx")
If Not wbTemporariosBruto Is Nothing Then

    Set wsSheet = wbTemporariosBruto.Sheets("Temporarios Ativos")
    Set wsTempActivos = wbTHMacro.Sheets("Temp Activos")
    wsSheet.Cells.Copy wsTempActivos.Range("A1")
    Set wsSheet = wbTemporariosBruto.Sheets("JA Ativos")
    Set wsTempJA = wbTHMacro.Sheets("Temp JA")
    wsSheet.Cells.Copy wsTempJA.Range("A1")
    Set wsSheet = wbTemporariosBruto.Sheets("Aprendizes FIT")
    Set wsTempFit = wbTHMacro.Sheets("Temp Fit")
    wsSheet.Cells.Copy wsTempFit.Range("A1")
    Set wsSheet = wbTemporariosBruto.Sheets("Demitidos")
    Set wsTempDemitidos = wbTHMacro.Sheets("Temp Demitidos")
    wsSheet.Cells.Copy wsTempDemitidos.Range("A1")
    wbTemporariosBruto.Close False
Else
    Exit Sub
End If

Set wbPresenceSystem = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="H:\BX-HR\BX-INDUSTRIAL RELATIONS\HR REPRESENTATIVES\PRIVATE\HRSSC\Brazil\Training Hours Macro\Presence System Bruto.xls")
If Not wbPresenceSystem Is Nothing Then

    'Set wsSheet = wsTPCC.Sheets("TPCC")
    Set wsPS = wbTHMacro.Sheets("PS")
    'wsSheet.Cells.Copy wsTempActivos.Range("A1")

    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "CC"
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("D1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "MO"
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "38697263859*"
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="*", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                      ReplaceFormat:=False
    Cells.Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Selection.RowHeight = 15
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter

    Sheets("TreimentosPorCentroDeCusto (5)").Select
    Sheets("TreimentosPorCentroDeCusto (5)").Name = "TPCC"

    Set wsSheet = wsTPCC.Sheets("TPCC")
    Set wsPS = wbTHMacro.Sheets("PS")
    wsSheet.Cells.Copy wsTempActivos.Range("A1")
    wbPresenceSystem.Close False
Else
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: wsTPCC is a Worksheet, not Workbook, so it doesn't have a Sheets property.

Comment: Thanks I got what you meant... `Set wsSheet = wbPresenceSystem.Sheets("TPCC")` But now I have an even bigger problem... Its deleting the data in column A in the PS Sheet upon importing it... Any clues as o why?

Comment: Because you told it to here `Selection.Replace What:="*", Replacement:=""`. If you wanted to replace asterisks, use `Selection.Replace What:="~*", Replacement:=""`

Comment: The report has numbers like this "38697263859 " with a space at the end so I want the macro to delete the SPACE at the end of every number in column A... another question is that the sheet name will vary and I would like to change the name to TPCC no matter what the name of the sheet in the presence System workbook may be... Is there anyway to alter the code to do this? `Sheets("TreimentosPorCentroDeCusto (5)").Select
    Sheets("TreimentosPorCentroDeCusto (5)").Name = "TPCC"`

Comment: Then use `Selection.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:=""`. How would you identify the sheet to rename?

Comment: Using the replace function only replaced the space at the end of the first series of numbers in column A or in cell A2, but not the whole column... the sheet can be identified because it will always contain the words TreimentosPorCentroDeCusto but the number at the end will change and sometimes it will not even have a number...

Comment: It appears you're getting the help you want elsewhere so I'll leave them to it. :)

Comment: Thanks needed the help...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for the macro just in case:

```
Option Explicit
Sub TrainingHoursMacro()

Dim wbTHMacro As Workbook, wsRegulares As Worksheet, wsRegularesDemitidos As Worksheet, wsTempActivos As Worksheet, wsTempJA As Worksheet, wsTempFit As Worksheet, _
wsTempDemitidos As Worksheet, wsPS As Worksheet, wsResultados As Worksheet, wsDLList As Worksheet, wssheet As Worksheet
Dim wbRegularesBruto As Workbook, wsMovimentacao As Worksheet, wsDemitidos As Worksheet
Dim wbTemporariosBruto As Workbook, wsTemporariosAtivos As Worksheet, wsJAAtivos As Worksheet, wsAprendizesFit As Worksheet
Dim wbPresenceSystem As Workbook, wsTPCC As Worksheet
Dim wbFlexUTrainingHours As Workbook, wsHours As Worksheet, wsFlexU As Worksheet
Dim rcell As Range

Set wbTHMacro = Workbooks("Training Hours Macro.xlsm")
Set wsRegulares = wbTHMacro.Sheets("Regulares")
wsRegulares.Cells.ClearContents

Set wbRegularesBruto = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="H:\BX-HR\BX-INDUSTRIAL RELATIONS\HR REPRESENTATIVES\PRIVATE\HRSSC\Brazil\Training Hours Macro\Regulares Bruto.xls")
If Not wbRegularesBruto Is Nothing Then

Set wssheet = wbRegularesBruto.Sheets("Movimentacao")
    wssheet.Cells.Copy wsRegulares.Range("A1")
        Set wssheet = wbRegularesBruto.Sheets("Demitidos")
Set wsRegularesDemitidos = wbTHMacro.Sheets("Regulares Demitidos")
    wssheet.Cells.Copy wsRegularesDemitidos.Range("A1")
        wbRegularesBruto.Close False
Else
    Exit Sub
            End If

Set wbTemporariosBruto = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="H:\BX-HR\BX-INDUSTRIAL RELATIONS\HR REPRESENTATIVES\PRIVATE\HRSSC\Brazil\Training Hours Macro\Temporarios Bruto.xlsx")
If Not wbTemporariosBruto Is Nothing Then

Set wssheet = wbTemporariosBruto.Sheets("Temporarios Ativos")
    Set wsTempActivos = wbTHMacro.Sheets("Temp Activos")
    wssheet.Cells.Copy wsTempActivos.Range("A1")
Set wssheet = wbTemporariosBruto.Sheets("JA Ativos")
    Set wsTempJA = wbTHMacro.Sheets("Temp JA")
    wssheet.Cells.Copy wsTempJA.Range("A1")
Set wssheet = wbTemporariosBruto.Sheets("Aprendizes FIT")
    Set wsTempFit = wbTHMacro.Sheets("Temp Fit")
    wssheet.Cells.Copy wsTempFit.Range("A1")
Set wssheet = wbTemporariosBruto.Sheets("Demitidos")
    Set wsTempDemitidos = wbTHMacro.Sheets("Temp Demitidos")
    wssheet.Cells.Copy wsTempDemitidos.Range("A1")
        wbTemporariosBruto.Close False
Else
    Exit Sub
            End If

Set wbPresenceSystem = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="H:\BX-HR\BX-INDUSTRIAL RELATIONS\HR REPRESENTATIVES\PRIVATE\HRSSC\Brazil\Training Hours Macro\Presence System Bruto.xls")
If Not wbPresenceSystem Is Nothing Then

Set wsPS = wbTHMacro.Sheets("PS")

    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "CC"
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("D1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "MO"
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "38697263859 "

       For Each rcell In Range("A2:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3)(1).Row)
    rcell.Value = Left(rcell, Len(rcell) - 1)
    'rcell.Value = Trim(rcell)
Next rcell

    Cells.Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Selection.RowHeight = 15
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter

For Each wssheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Left(wssheet.Name, 27) = "TreimentosPorCentroDeCustro" Then
    wssheet.Activate
    End If
    ActiveSheet.Name = "TPCC"
    Exit For
Next wssheet

Set wssheet = wbPresenceSystem.Sheets("TPCC")
    Set wsPS = wbTHMacro.Sheets("PS")
    wssheet.Cells.Copy wsPS.Range("A1")
    wbPresenceSystem.Close False
Else
    Exit Sub
            End If

Set wbFlexUTrainingHours = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="H:\BX-HR\BX-INDUSTRIAL RELATIONS\HR REPRESENTATIVES\PRIVATE\HRSSC\Brazil\Training Hours Macro\Flex U Training Hours.xls")
If Not wbFlexUTrainingHours Is Nothing Then

For Each wssheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Left(wssheet.Name, 29) = "Training_Hours_12_37_24_PM 1 " Then
    wssheet.Activate
    End If
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Hours"
    Exit For
Next wssheet

Set wssheet = wbFlexUTrainingHours.Sheets("Hours")
    Set wsFlexU = wbTHMacro.Sheets("Flex U")
    wssheet.Cells.Copy wsFlexU.Range("A1")
        wbFlexUTrainingHours.Close False
Else
    Exit Sub
            End If

End Sub
```